# Insert COUNT into a Query

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I had already asked and get this query:

```
SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) as ranking, p.* FROM (SELECT player, COUNT(*) as cnt
  FROM test
  WHERE statistic=0 AND time > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
  GROUP BY player
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc
 ) p CROSS JOIN
 (SELECT @rn := 0) params LIMIT 10;
```

But now I want to get another value:

```
COUNT(*) as cnt2 FROM test WHERE statistic=1 AND time > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

How can I insert the query in the other query above, to get "cnt2"?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edited: , instead of AND clause

`SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) as ranking, p.* FROM (SELECT player, COUNT(*) as cnt, COUNT(*) as cnt2
  FROM test
  WHERE statistic=0 AND time > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
  GROUP BY player
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc
 ) p CROSS JOIN
 (SELECT @rn := 0) params LIMIT 10;`

Comment: This query does not work :( I want in "cnt2" only the amount where statistic=1 and not 0

Comment: Edited. Try use , instead of AND clause.

Comment: Yes, that works. But I want not the same values. "cnt2" counted when statistic is 1 and not 0